# Load multiple pieces of datasets in python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dataset

I would like to have a unique dataset, like a single .csv file with all my data in it.

**The problem:** the whole datasets is divided into 22 folders, one for each user (see images below) and then, for each user, there are 7 .csv files which correspond to statistic data for each user.

I would like to merge all these datasets all in one, possibly with indexes that indicates users (for rows). The pictures are these :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX0dc.png

For each user:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZazG.png

The code I tried to write below for an idea;
I would like to insert a for all the user, changing the path with "DataPaper/user_i.sleep.csv", and i don't know how to do it because I don't master python. Also add the other features, not only the "sleep.cvs"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r315i.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand, you are trying to read multiple dataFrames and concatenate. But you want to avoid to do write the same sentences.
This is not exactly the solution but you can do something like:

```
#this create a list of users
userList = [f"user_{i}" for i in range(1,22)] 

#read all df
dfList = []
for user in userList:
    thisDF = pd.read_csv(f"DataPaper/{user}/sleep.csv")
    dfList.append(thisDF)
    
result = pd.concat(dfList,keys = userList)
```

if this not work properly let me know!!
cheers!